# precompiled header name gets stuck

Tags: xcode, macos, precompiled-headers

I'm new to xcode and I must be missing something.

Create a new command-line project.  Call it tempprog (for instance).
Select Project/Edit Project Settings.
Edit the name of the prefix header (tempprog_Prefixz.pch).
Build - it will fail, of course, looking for tempprog_Prefixz.pch
Now change the name of the prefix header back to tempprog_Prefix.pch.
Build again - it should work, but doesn't.  It's still looking for tempprog_Prefixz.pch

Cleaning does not rectify the situation.  What am I missing here?  Where is the Prefixz.pch name being retained?  If you look in the build output at the ProcessPCH command you can see that it still wants to use Prefixz.

Comment: Ok.  I figured out how to fix it, but I still have some confusion.  

If you do a get info on the target, click on the build tab, and go to the prefix header setting, the Prefixz.pch name is in there.  I changed that back to tempprog_Prefix.pch and it built fine.  

But why would the settings found by right-clicking the target be different from the settings found when selecting project/edit project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there's a system of setting priorities.

From Working With Xcode Build Settings:

The levels at which build settings can be set, and their precedences are:

xcodebuild command-line flags (only applicable for command-line builds)
The target, editable via a target's Info inspector
The project, editable via a project's Info inspector
Xcode application settings, as set in Xcode > Preferences...
Xcode's built in defaults
The user environment, perhaps as set in a user's ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist file

Answer (score 0):

Restarting your mac fixes the problem.

Comment: I've reviewed the build settings, cleared derived date, restarted xcode, cleaned/build a million times. Only thing that ever corrects this weird bug is restarting my entire machine. Total pain but better than banging my head for an hour. Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)